# How to modify the tooltip for various eclipse commands e.g. Paste, Cut, Copy

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tooltip, eclipse-rcp, plugin.xml

I want to modify the existing tool tip text.I have following lines in plugin.xml

```
<command commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.paste" 
 id="org.eclipse.ui.edit.paste" tooltip="%pasteAction.TIP">
```

in plugin.properties

```
pasteAction.TIP=Paste
```

Existing tool tip appears like following

Paste(Ctrl+V)

I want to modify this existing tool tip to appears like following

**Paste(Ctrl+V)**
Paste a reference to the object

I am getting three problems to achieve this use case.

- (Ctrl+V) added automatically  at the end of tool tip text. which is not desired. It should appear where it is expected.
- don't know how to Bold the particular string e.g. (Ctrl+V)
- don't know how to make tool tip text multiline

we can use \n for multiline. it works but still looking for other two questions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For controls that you create you can use the `org.eclipse.jface.window.ToolTip` class to define custom tool tips.

For controls that Eclipse creates I don't know of any way to change the position of the key binding text or the font (bold).